# Is there not enough information for $\frac{S_{11}}{S_8} = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $S_1 + S_6 = 1024$
>
> and $S_3 . S_4 = 1023$
>
> $S_n$ is sum of n terms geometric sequence

find $\frac{S_{11}}{S_8} $

you can just expand it

$$a + \frac{a (r^6 - 1)}{r-1} = 1024$$

and

$$\frac{a (r^3 - 1)}{r-1}. \frac{a (r^4 - 1)}{r-1} = 1023$$

but, is there no enough information for this question?

Comment: Two equations in two unknowns is enough information, Life, but that doesn't mean it's easy. Is there any chance that when you wrote $S_n$ is the sum of $n$ terms, you really meant it's the $n$th term?

Comment: Also, the title refers to $S_{11}/S_8$, but those aren't in the body. Please edit the title or the body so they are consistent.

Comment: yes it is the sum of elements not the $n$th element.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2B+%28a%28r%5E6-1%29%29%2F%28r-1%29+%3D+1024++%2C+%28a%28r%5E3-1%29%2F%28r-1%29%29*%28a%28r%5E4-1%29%2F%28r-1%29%29+%3D+1023) yields $a≈0.763701, r≈3.98409$ and $a≈1022.5, r≈-1$ as the solution.

Comment: @The, question has been edited, OP wants $S_{11}/S_8$.